# Not enough workers when trying to access a site with NGINX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, sonarqube

I am trying to create a Sonarqube in a Ubuntu virtual machine with Vagrant and using Nginx. I have followed all the steps but when I try to access I get a `502 BadGateway` and checking the logs I get the following:

```
2020/01/29 18:44:05 [alert] 1205#1205: 768 worker_connections are not enough
2020/01/29 18:44:05 [error] 1205#1205: *2090 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: sonarqube.developerinsider.co, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0", upstream: "
```

This is the configuration I have for the site:

```
upstream sonar {
 server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server{
listen      9000;
server_name sonarqube.developerinsider.co;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/sonar.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/sonar.error.log;

proxy_buffers 16 64k;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;

location / {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;

}
}
```

This is my Vagrant File:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1804"
 config.vm.box_check_update = true
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "XXX.XX.XX.XX"
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8081, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
 config.vm.hostname = "tracker.tlc.vm"
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 vb.memory = "4096"
end
end
```

However I can access the Jenkins I have in it and the Nginx's default site. I try to access using the following IP: `http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:9000/`

Comment: Are you sure of your config? The server is listening on port `9000` and is a proxy for himself: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000`?

Comment: I am not, I am very new in these matters so I followed the following tutorial: https://developerinsider.co/install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial you cite](https://developerinsider.co/install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/) contains a typo. The **Nginx** config should look like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        ...
    }
}
```

This way **nginx** will be available under `http://<server's IP>/`, while Sonarqube under `http://<server's IP>:9000/`. By the way **Sonarqube** is not running on your server, otherwise **nginx** could not possibly use port `9000`.

What is happening now: when a request comes, **nginx** forwards the request to `127.0.0.1:9000`, i.e. himself. This cause an infinite loop of forwards, which ends up when **nginx** runs out of workers to deal with them.

You should inform the tutorial's author of the typo.

Comment: Now I get this on the logs: `31535#31535: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)` using the IP `http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:9000` and the browser gives this error: `400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large`
I have checked and sonarqube is up and running.

Comment: You need to restart **nginx**, so it will free port `9000` and move to port `80` and start **Sonarqube**. The site should be available as `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`.

Comment: I restarted nginx and sonarqube and using `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is redirecting me to nginx's default site. Do I need to disable default site first?

Comment: Yes, and change the listen directive to `listen 80 default;` to be sure.

Comment: I disabled the default site and changed the listen directive but I get the 404 error I mentioned above and logs show this: `accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)`

Comment: Another loop must have happened. Can you read the **Sonarqube** server on `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9000` by passing this way **nginx**?

Comment: I get the same error using that url.

Comment: So it is a Sonarqube problem then (on that URL Sonarqube is listening).